# Llamar función JS externa desde archivo PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un achivo `functions.js` que tiene esta única función

```
export const setLang = (lang) => {
    let path = '';
    if(lang == 'es'){
        path = window.location.pathname.replace('/en/', '/');
    }else if(lang == 'en'){
        path = window.location.pathname.replace('/xxx/', '/xxx/en/')
    }
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin+path)
}
```

Luego desde un archivo `header.php` agrego la línea

```
<script src="/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(estoy bastante seguro que la ruta está bien, `header.php` y la carpeta `js` están al mismo nivel, probé de la manera que ya indiqué, y `js/functions.js` y `./js/functions.js`

> Cabe aclarar que `header.php` es un html `<header></header>` que se llama desde distintos lugares del sitio con la funcion `include` de `php`. Probé poner el script al principio, al medio, o al final.

Lo que yo espero es que al clickear en un span se ejecute la funcion `setLang`

```
<span class="custom-option" onclick="setLang('en')" data-value="en">EN</span>
```

Pero la consola me arroja

> index.php:411 Uncaught ReferenceError: setLang is not defined
> at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

No sé si el error está en la forma de exportar del javascript, o la importacion desde PHP. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Probaste quitando la palabra `export`? De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) se usa solo en módulos y, además, deberías importarlo antes de poder usarlo.

Comment: Revisaste la consola del navegador?... lo mas probable es que esté saltando algún error cuando intentas incluir el script

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 3 cosas

**numero 1:**

> Para poder usar la sentencia export, el script debe estar declarado
> como tipo `module`.

```
<script src="/js/functions.js" type="module"></script>
```

**numero 2:**

Al declarar un `script` como tipo `module` para poder que funcione el modulo deberas ejecutar la pagina en un servidor, protocolos como `file://` **DEJAN DE SER VALIDOS**, en tu caso no tendras problemas, porque si estas usando `PHP` debes estar corriendo tu codigo en un servidor, `apache` por ej.

**numero 3:**

Si vas a usar modulos para poder usar tu función exportada primero deberas importarla con un `import`.

En tu caso no estas necesitando usarla en otro `script` si no en la misma pagina, por lo que realmente no necesitaras una sentencia `import`, sin embargo, justo por esto ultimo (no necesitas importar esa función en otro archivo), no tiene sentido declarar el script como tipo modulo.

Tiene mucho menos sentido exportarlo.

conclusión:

Para tu caso, al no tener que hacer uso de esa función en un `script` aparte si no en la misma pagina es mejor simplemente que no uses la sentencia `export`.

Por lo tanto tambien te recomendaria no usar el `type = module` para tu caso, ya que realmente no lo necesitas.

Entonces en este caso, la verdad seria mejor no aplicar los modulos, pues lo que tu necesitas no es usar eso en otro `script`, si no en la misma pagina.

Por lo tanto tu codigo queda de esta manera:

**functions.js:**

```
const setLang = (lang) => {
    let path = '';
    if(lang == 'es'){
        path = window.location.pathname.replace('/en/', '/');
    }else if(lang == 'en'){
        path = window.location.pathname.replace('/xxx/', '/xxx/en/')
    }
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin+path)
}
```

Ahora bien, para que te reconozca la funcion, tienes que tener en cuenta que como estas tratando de usar la funcion en html en linea:

```
<span class="custom-option" onclick="setLang('en')" data-value="en">EN</span>
```

El script debera a fuerzas ser declarado `ANTES` de los elementos donde uses estas funciones.

por ejemplo antes del cierre del `head`:

```
<head>
...
...
<script src="/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Y si bien esto funcionaria, no seria exactamente lo mejor, normalmente seria mas viable nunca usar html en linea y comenzar a usar algo llamado `encapsulamiento`, pero esto ya es tema de otro costal.

Por lo que dejo este ultimo concepto para otra pregunta.